# How to hide first item from an Html Select Tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, select

I have the following code:

```
<select>
    <option value="0">Option 0</option>.
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

When you click on select I wish the first item to be no longer listed. Also it must work on all browsers. How can this be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you are using the first option as a substitute for a `<label>`. Don't do that, write proper markup instead.

Comment: @David - write that up as an answer since it's correct.

Comment: <label> is not what I realy need.

Comment: @annakata — It's the X-Y problem. I think it answers X, but the question (unless edited) is still Y and we can only assume we know what X is. http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select id="selectBox"
  onFocus="javascript:nullOpt=document.getElementById('nullOpt');
           (undefined != nullOpt) ?
           document.getElementById('selectBox').removeChild(nullOpt) :
           true;"
  onBlur="javascript:insertBefore(
                          nullOpt,
                          document.getElementById('selectBox').firstChild
                     );">
  <option id="nullOpt">Please select...</option>
  <option>val1</option>
  <option>val2</option>
  <option>val3</option>
</select>
```

​EDIT: Added newly requested functionality, sort of.

Comment: Unless you select any item and "select" tag lose focus how to redisplay first element?

Comment: You didn't mention that you wanted to ever redisplay it and I assumed that if they focused on the select box then they would know to select something at that point.  You could assign nullOpt to another variable and re-add it onBlur if you wanted.

Comment: fixed to show how to do that, but I think this will clear their selection.  You might want to re-think your functionality spec.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add display:none to the first option. First option will appear only as a "header" of the select box, not in the options anymore. It works on Firefox & Chrome.

```html
<select>
    <option style="display:none;" value="0">Option 0</option>.
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

hmmmm not sure that editing collections like that is going to work 100% of the time.  If you dont supply a value for the select item then you should be able to throw a validation error as no "Value" is selected.

```
<select> 
    <option value="">Select a value...</option> 
    <option value="1">Option 1</option> 
    <option value="2">Option 2</option> 
</select>
```

then use one of the [JQuery validation libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to validate it.

Comment: I don't need to validate. I want to show the first option only for information.

Comment: It's an `<option>`. It isn't designed to provide information (other than "This is something you can pick") to the user.